# SP2007: Setting DefaultValue for WebURL in SPDataSource

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer

In Sharepoint 2007, I attempted to create an SPDataSource, needed for a repeater element, that looks something similar to this:

```
 <SPWebControls:SPDataSource runat="server" 
             ID="dsColors" 
             DataSourceMode="ListItem" 
             UseInternalName="true">   
  <SelectParameters>      
      <asp:Parameter Name="ListName" DefaultValue="AllColors"/>
      <asp:Parameter Name="WebUrl" DefaultValue="??????" />      
      <asp:Parameter Name="ContentTypeFilter" DefaultValue="Index Page"/>
  </SelectParameters>
</SPWebControls:SPDataSource>
```

AllColors is a list at rainbow.com that shows up in the Sharepoint Administration page that's titled "All Site Content"
The displayed breadcrumb is "Home > All Site Content"
The URL is "http://rainbow.com/_layouts/viewlsts.aspx

My question is what should DefaultValue be set equal to for this line:

```
    <asp:Parameter Name="WebUrl" DefaultValue="??????" />
```

Also, please provide a reference to any docs discussing the use of spdatasource and its parameters. I've searched extensively and could not find a good article that

shows various examples.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use instead:

```
<asp:Parameter Name="WebID" DefaultValue="RootWeb" />
```